# Adobe InDesign/Typesetting: No kerning possible for first letter in indented line?

Tags: adobe-indesign, typesetting, kerning

In `Adobe InDesign`, I have setup a `paragraph style` for a sub-headline which has the headline as well as the first line of the following paragraph indented. In some instances, the sub-headline runs over two lines and the alignment of the first letters sometimes is rather unappealing. I understand that kerning usually means the adjustment of the space between two letters, but is there also a method of tweaking the alignment/spacing in such cases? Please refer to the screenshots below. Here, I would like to nudge the »V« in the second line a little further in but I can't find any way to do so.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

With your headline text selected, enable the "Optical Margin Alignment" feature, found under "Window > Type & Tables > Story", change that amount to your font size and try different values until it looks good. Play with it a bit.

Read more at https://indesignsecrets.com/tip-of-the-week-using-optical-margin-alignment.php and google it for different ways to use this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In this case, I typically insert a space before the letter in question, then highlight the blank space, and decrease the kerning of it. This allows more control over letters which don't quite line up correctly.

[image]

Comment: This could work, but not very elegant.

Comment: "Form over function" is not always the best solution. ;)